# Help with designing sales and inventory management system

Tags: database-design

I need to make a sale and inventory management system. I'm stuck on the purchasing price and stock for the product.

Let's say you bought 10 t-shirt for $10 per t-shirt and selling them at $20 per t-shirt.

You sold 8 t-shirt quickly and decided to buy 10 more. Now, the price is $12 per t-shirt.

Now , you've total 12 t-shirt in stock, where 2 t-shirts purchasing price is $10 and 10 t-shirts purchasing price is $12.

How can I make a product table which will keep track of the purchasing price at different times for the product and also the total stock ?

Comment: For any future questions you might have, It would likely help you to understand this (and us, too) if you try creating a [mcve] using standard SQL, with some sample data, and what you want any potential output query results to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Product` table shouldn't store the `Price` at all. You need a separate table called something like `Purchases` which has a row for every purchase made, the `Price` and `PurchasedDate`, and a foreign key field to reference the `Product` table.

Also, tables like `Purchases` and `Sales` are normally broken out further into two tables each. One table having header information and the other the line information. For example, `PurchaseOrders` would store the header information like `PurchasedDate`, `PurchasedBy`, maybe the `Company` purchased from (if only one Company can be on one Order), where the `PurchaseLines` table would be a row for every item purchased on that `PurchaseOrder`, with the `Quantity` (per item), `Price`, and foreign key field to relate back to the `PurchaseOrders` table. Similar structure for `SalesOrders` and `SalesLines`.

`PurchaseOrders` are one-to-many `PurchaseLines`. (`SalesOrders` are one-to-many `SalesLines.`)